# why is my raw socket not being created?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

This is my code. It doesn't give any errors during compiling. But when I run it, it gives

> Recv from error , failed to get packets

error. What is wrong?

```
logfile=fopen("log.txt","w");
if(logfile==NULL) printf("Unable to create file.");
printf("Starting...\n");
//Create a raw socket that shall sniff
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);

if(sock_raw < 0)
{
    printf("Socket Error\n");
    return 1;
}
while(1)
{
    saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
    if(data_size <0 )
    {
        printf("Recv from error , failed to get packets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Now process the packet
    ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
}
close(sock_raw);
printf("Finished");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: check errno and see if that gives you a clue.

Comment: Errno 107 means that the socket is NOT connected (any more). There are several reasons why this could happen. Assuming you're right and both sides of the connection claim that the socket is still open, an intermediate router/switch may have dropped the connection due to a timeout. The safest way to avoid such things from happen is to periodically send a 'health' or 'keep-alive' message.

But how do I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you use raw TCP sockets instead or normal SOCK_STREAM? TCP has lots of stuff built-in to make sure all packets are transmitted/received and that they are received in the order they were transmitted. By using raw sockets you have to keep track of windows sizes, transmissions, three-way handshake, connection resets all by yourself. And of course parsing and creating the actual IP and TCP headers. The problem here might be that you do not handle the three-way handshake, so the connection is never connected properly.

Comment: Please show the declaration of all the relevant variables: saddr, saddr_size, etc.

Comment: What operating system are you on? XP SP2 does not allow raw sockets btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just sniff all ethernet traffic, use the following:

```
sock_raw = socket( PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL) )
```

Usually raw sockets works only for the root user under UNIX or Linux.

Some older Windows does not allow raw sockets at all.

Type of `saddr` should be:

```
struct sockaddr_ll
```

Answer (score 2):

when u will run the executable file just use sudo command before ./executablefilename .
like :$gcc pack.c -o pack
and then
$sudo ./pack
then it will run fine
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter that problem in the past. to create RAW socket you need to run an executable with admin privileges.